# Debug source-code of Node-RED open source project

Tags: javascript, debugging, node-red

I want to debug Node-red project source code. When I type a command as the following

```
node --debug-brk red.js
```

and open my Visual Studio Code as the following

[image]

I could achieve debug process partly. But I want to debug on front-end side which is view.js. I can not debug view.js aforementioned method. If I would try to debug via Chrome or another browser I cannot see the view.js file in Sources segment.

[image]

How can I debug a js file if I would not see on the Web Browser.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Node-RED runs normally it uses a compressed build of all the browser side javascript, this is why you can't find the view.js as it's been minified and bundled up with a bunch of other stuff.

If you have downloaded the source from github the instructions include a step which tells you to run `grunt build` this is what does that minifying. (bottom of here: http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/installation)

If you run `grunt dev` instead it will start Node-RED without using the minified content and you should get the full version of the javascript to work with.

Comment: I tried what you have written here but result didn't change. Still don't have ui folder.I added manually UI folder into Google Chrome Debugger but I think it doesn't seem right

Comment: Assuming you didn't run `grunt build` it should be all you need to do, otherwise you could remove the build directory, but I'm 90% sure you shouldn't need to